# How do i select multiple rows which match the value of an item in an array?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have written a php script that returns an arbitrary number of specific ids (which are in the format of numbers) in an array. I would like to make a new query that selects each row from a table that belongs to each id. I know i can do 1 query to get one row with the matching id. But i would like to do this all in one query. Here is my code:

```
$id = array(1,4,7,3,11,120); // The array containing the ids

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM posts 
                       WHERE id = '$id[0]'"); 
// I would like to Do this for each id in the array and return it as one group of rows.`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PHP's implode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert the array into a comma separated value string.

Then, you can use the [SQL IN clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) to run a single SQL statement containing the values associated with the ids you captured from PHP:

```
$id = array(1,4,7,3,11,120);
$csv = implode(',', $id); 

$query = sprintf("SELECT * 
                    FROM posts 
                   WHERE id IN (%s)",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($csv)); 

$result = mysql_query($query)
```

I omitted the single quotes because they aren't necessary when dealing with numeric values in SQL.  If the `id` values were strings, each would have to be encapsulated inside of single quotes.

Comment: does the mysql_real_escape_string() escape each of the values in the array? or does it escape the array in general? i have never used it in this way.

Comment: @Ben: It doesn't escape each value.  It's a poor example because of the numeric data, but if your array contained characters that were illegal to SQL/MySQL -- the illegal characters would be properly escaped.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the [`IN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) clause:

```
$idList = implode(",", $id);

SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE id IN ( $idList );
```

The [`implode()`](http://ca.php.net/implode) function will turn your array of numbers into a comma-separated string of those same values. When you use it as part of an `IN` clause, it tells the database to use those values as a lookup table to match `id` against.

**Standard Disclaimer/Warning:**
As with *any* SQL query, you really shouldn't be directly concatenating variables into the query string. You're just opening yourself up to SQL injection. Use prepared/parameterized statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is SQL's `IN` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN (1, 4, 7, 11, 120)
```

In PHP, you'll probably want something like:

```
$query = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN (%s)", implode(',', $id)));
```

Obviously, that's assuming you know you have integer values for $id, and that the values for $id didn't come from the user (that is, they should be sanitized). To be safe, you really ought to do something like:

```
$ids = implode(',', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $id));
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN ($ids)");
```

And if $id is dynamically generated, don't forget to put *something* in that IN clause, because `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ()` will give you an error. I generally make sure to set my IN-clause variables to 0, since `IN (0)` is good, and primary keys are pretty much never 0.